# Office 2007 and Office 2010 installed side by side

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2010

I have Office 2007 and Office 2010 installed side-by-side. How do I stop the setup / configuration window from appearing each time I open a different version? If I open 2007, it will go through the configuration process, then I can use 2007 without issue until I open a 2010 application. Then, when I open any 2010 Office application it will go through the configuration process.

Comment: This had been an issue for us with 2003 and 2007 for a long time before we ditched 2003 altogether. But that probably doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find a solution posted on the following blog: http://uksbsguy.com/blogs/doverton/archive/2007/07/21/how-to-get-rid-of-the-installer-configuration-dialog-when-running-office-2007-and-office-2003-on-the-same-system-for-vista-and-other-versions-of-windows.aspx
The solution was to add a registry key as specified below for both Office 12.0 (Office 2007) and Office 14 (Office 2010). I only had to do this with one application (Word) to stop the configuration wizard from appearing each time I opened any office application.

reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Options /v NoReReg /t REG_DWORD /d 1
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\Options /v NoReReg /t REG_DWORD /d 1

Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be to use virtual machines to isolate the two versions of Office. If you have Windows 7 Pro or higher you can install XP Mode and put one of the versions of office in the VM. Otherwise VirtualBox is a great VM host.

Comment: This is my solution for a development environment; however, it is too resource intensive for a production environment. Our company does not currently support Windows 7 so VPC 2007 or VirtualBox are my only real options. Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the versions you don't want. IMHO, Office 2010 is just enough. by default, office files will be opened with 2007.

Comment: I wish I had that liberty. I am developing Office add-ins for our company and the majority of users will be on 2007. I however, don't want to give up Office 2010 just so  I can develop against 2007.

Comment: could you help us by showing off configuration window you've faced ?